# Is safe to use "X-..." header in a HTTP response?

Tags: http, http-headers

I have to pass a meta-information in my HTTP response so I figured out that I could use the response header, for instance "X-MyData: 123456". Is that safe? I mean, there is a possibility that a client proxy remove this header?

Thanks!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

A client proxy could do anything it wanted, but in general would not strip any headers.

Headers starting with an X- are typically reserved for nonstandard usage (i.e. no future standard will introduce a header starting X-) but a proxy may understand them and choose to modify them as it wants.

Answer (score 33):

For reference, X- headers are also referred to as `x-token` in the BNF of [RFC 2045](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2045.txt), as `user-defined ("X-")` in section 5 of [RFC 2047](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2047.txt) and as Experimental headers in section 4.2.2.1 of the [News Article Format](http://www.eyrie.org/~eagle/usefor/drafts/draft-ietf-usefor-article-06.txt) draft.

[Deprecating Use of the "X-" Prefix in Application Protocols](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc6648.txt) (BCP, June 2012):

> deprecates the "X-" convention for most application protocols and
>   makes specific recommendations about how to proceed in a world without
>   the distinction between standard and non-standard parameters

Answer (score 11):

It *is* possible for proxy servers or any intermediate links in the chain to modify your headers, but this *usually* isn't a problem.

More often than not, specifying custom headers is fine as long as they're unique enough not to conflict with other people's headers and you don't expect anyone else to use yours.