# What HTTP code to use in "Not Authenticated" and "Not authorized" cases?

Tags: http, language-agnostic, http-status-codes

I read that ["401 Unauthorized"](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) code must be used when a user:

1. Is not logged, but login is required ("not authenticated");
2. Is logged, but his profile don't allow to see that url ("not authorized");

According to RFC, in both cases server must return `401` code.
But I need to differentiate then in my ajax requests.

Anybody have a tip to solve this?

Note: I don't want to use `403 Forbidden` code, because in 403 `"Authorization will not help"`, according to RFC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass a custom header in addition to the status code for application specific needs.

I believe the current practice is to preface custom headers with `X-`

### Update, August 2012:

From the [RFC 3864](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3864) posted in the comments (dated September 2004):

> In some cases (notably HTTP [24]), the header syntax and usage is
> redefined for the specific application.
> [...]
> In some cases, the same field name may be specified differently (by
> different documents) for use with different application protocols.
> [...]
> We need to accommodate application-specific fields, while wishing to
> recognize and promote (where appropriate) commonality of other fields
> across multiple applications.

In a more recent RFC ([6648](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6648), dated June 2012), they specifically address `X-` headers.

> Deprecates the "X-" convention for newly defined parameters in
> application protocols, including new parameters for established
> protocols. [...] Does not recommend against the practice of private,
> local, preliminary, experimental, or implementation-specific
> parameters, only against the use of "X-" and similar constructs in the
> names of such parameters.

Important to note is that while `X-` is **specifically** noted, they do still implicitly condone custom headers as a way of transferring information.  An application specific prefix (`MyApp-`) might be more appropriate to avoid ever colliding with any other headers.

See also: [Is it safe to use "X-" header in a HTTP response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1810915/is-safe-to-use-x-header-in-a-http-response) from a few years ago.

Comment: "X-" isn't special in HTTP header fields. See RFC 3864.

Comment: Wait, did you seriously downvote me for this?  The "Standard" not by definition since, had you read the definition, you would see that defining application specific headers is up to the application designer: there is no standard.  It's a "standard" because that's how most people do it, and it's been accepted that `X-` typically denotes a custom header that the browser can ignore for regular operation.

Comment: Just because it's "current practice" doesn't mean it is the right thing to do.  There are much better ways to qualify specifically what a HTTP status code means. e.g. Returning a body with details.

Comment: A custom header is only meaningful if you *also* have a custom browser that will interpret it. Otherwise, everything will ignore your custom header and it will have no effect whatsoever.

Comment: @tylerl The assumption would be that the custom header is being interpreted either by a server-side application or a client-side application, both of which would be a precursor to even using the custom headers. If you're trying to cause the browser to automatically do something, then you would have to use one of the pre-defined response codes, or use a custom browser as you suggest.

Answer (score 48):

Unless you intend to use HTTP authentication, the correct response is 403 ("Forbidden").

A response code of 401 triggers the browser to display a password dialog box, and then resubmit the same request with a `Authorization` header with the password data that the user supplied. That's probably not the behavior you want.

Don't get too hung up on the explanations in the RFCs -- what you really need to pay attention to are the browser and search engine side effects of the various response codes.

As for the `"Authorization will not help"` bit, in this case that is correct, since using HTTP authorization (which specifically means the `Authorization` header), in fact, will not help.

A 403 response tells the browser that the user does not have permission to make that request, and the browser should **not** attempt to collect authentication data and resubmit the request. That's exactly the response you're after.

Comment: `WWW-Authenticate` is a [*response*](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/WWW-Authenticate) header, not a *request* header.

Comment: @Suleyman oops yep, you're right; it's supposed to be `Authorization` instead. 13 years and nobody noticed. Corrected.

Answer (score 9):

I believe 403 is the right one. We may have to tune the language in the specification to make that clear.

Comment: In the spirit of your pettiness, here's the [RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2068.txt) showing that your answer is completely and clearly wrong, by design.  It's section 10.4.4

Comment: rockerest; first of all RFC 2068 has been obsoleted by RFC 2616 a long time ago. Second, I *believe* to use 403 is the right choice (see tylerl's answer), and if the text in the spec suggests otherwise, we should consider changing it. Yes, we can.

Comment: (the question is now tracked in the HTTPbis Working Group as http://trac.tools.ietf.org/wg/httpbis/trac/ticket/294)

Comment: This is excellent news.  This ambiguity in the spec has been confusing me for a while.

Answer (score 2):

IIS differentiates these cases with sub-status codes ([reference](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/c9511f97-d898-4aed-b0a8-979ce30d85b5.mspx?mfr=true)):

- 401 = User is not logged in, but login is required
- 401.1 = The user tried to login but their credentials are not valid.
- 401.3 = The user's credentials are valid but the user is not authorized to see the resource.

Comment: Which, IIRC, aren't valid per the [HTTP spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html#sec6.1): "Status-Line = HTTP-Version SP **Status-Code SP** Reason-Phrase CRLF [...] The Status-Code element is a **3-digit integer** result code" (emphasis mine)

Comment: I haven't tested it but I guess that IIS only sends 3-digit standard codes in the status line.  The substatus is sent in the 'reason phrase', some proprietary header or in the response body only, if it is sent at all.

Comment: These differentiated status indicators are used internally by IIS to show a different error page depending on the reason for showing the error.